# Reactjs form submit involving a controlled select component does not work

Tags: reactjs

In React, a form submit involving a controlled select component does not work.

It seems that React does not correctly set the 'selected' attribute in the actual dom.  You can see this in React's own example; https://codepen.io/gaearon/pen/JbbEzX?editors=0010 linked from the React documentation for the select component; https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#the-select-tag  The example looks like this;

```
class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: 'coconut'};

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('Your favorite flavor is: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
            <option value="lime">Lime</option>
            <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
            <option value="mango">Mango</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <FlavorForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

If you run the Codepen example and inspect the select menu in Chrome developer tools, you will see that initially, no option is selected.  Now choose an option and inspect again.  Still no option selected!!

In my own code, I have a controlled select menu I use to choose the month.  I have a callback to handle the onSubmit of the form.  It first calls preventDefault(), then does validation of the form, and if it validates, it calls event.currentTarget.submit() to complete the submit of the form.  What happens is that the validation succeeds (in particular validateChildBirthDate()), because the state is correct, but the submitted form fails validation on the server because the select menu in the encoded form has nothing selected.  My code is below, remember, the above code is the React documentation.

This is my code for the Month menu (I'm using TypeScript).  Note the console.log() that logs this.props.month; it logs the expected month value, but the associated option element is never given the 'selected' attribute in the real dom:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./DatePicker.scss";


export type MonthPickerProps = {
    name: string,       // 'menuId' attribute of select element
    month: number,                  // initially selected month
    onMonthChange(month: number): void   // callback when month changes
}

export default class MonthPicker extends React.Component<MonthPickerProps, {}, any> {

    onMonthChange = (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
        const month = Number(event.currentTarget.value);
        if('function' === typeof this.props.onMonthChange) {
            this.props.onMonthChange(month);
        }
    };

    render () {
        console.log(`MonthPicker.render(): month = ${this.props.month}`);

        return (
            <select name={this.props.name}
                    value={this.props.month}
                    onChange={this.onMonthChange}
                    className="monthPickerContainer dateSelector">
                <option key="-1" value="-1">mm</option>
                <option key="0"  value="0" >Jan</option>
                <option key="1"  value="1" >Feb</option>
                <option key="2"  value="2" >Mar</option>
                <option key="3"  value="3" >Apr</option>
                <option key="4"  value="4" >May</option>
                <option key="5"  value="5" >Jun</option>
                <option key="6"  value="6" >Jul</option>
                <option key="7"  value="7" >Aug</option>
                <option key="8"  value="8" >Sep</option>
                <option key="9"  value="9" >Oct</option>
                <option key="10" value="10">Nov</option>
                <option key="11" value="11">Dec</option>
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

This is my code from the stateful parent component that handles the onSubmit of the form component.  The validation will pass and so event.currentTarget.submit() will get called, but validation on the server will fail because the input value of the month select menu is always -1.

```
onRegistrationSubmit = (event: FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault(); // prevent default so we can validate

    // 1. validate email, if error, show error
    // 2. validate password, if error then show errors
    // 3. validate precon/due date, if error, show error
    // 4. else if no errors, collect fields and submit
    let showErrors = false;
    this.setState({showErrors: false});


    // 1. validate email, if error, show error
    const emailState = validateEmailState(this.state.email.value);
    if(isNotBlank(emailState.errorMessage)) {
        showErrors = true;
        this.setState({showErrors: true, email: emailState});
    }

    // 2. validate password, if error then show errors
    const passwordState = validatePasswordState(this.state.password.value);
    if(isNotBlank(passwordState.errorMessage)) {
        showErrors = true;
        this.setState({showErrors: true, password: passwordState});
    }

    // 3. validate precon/due date, if error, show error
    if(!this.state.isPrecon) {
        const childBirthDateState = validateChildBirthDate(this.state.birthDate.value);
        if(isNotBlank(childBirthDateState.errorMessage)) {
            showErrors = true;
            this.setState({showErrors: true, birthDate: childBirthDateState});
        }
    }

    // 4. else if no errors, collect fields and submit
    if(!showErrors) {
        event.currentTarget.submit();

        console.log("Registration submitted");
    }
};
```

Is this a known issue in the implementation of the select component?  Any work-arounds that you know of?

I'm using react and react-dom 16.7

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You can use `HTMLSelectElement.prototype.selectedIndex: number` and `HTMLSelectElement.prototype.selectedOptions: HTMLCollection` to access the selection of your `select`

Comment: Thanks @Limbo, the issue I have is with the 'normal' browser submit process.  Because the React select element does not maintain the 'selected' state on the real dom element, the form does not submit properly.  There are work arounds (I could create a form from my state and submit that), but that seems like is should not be necessary if the React select component is working correctly.  I'm really just trying to figure out if this is a bug in read or if I am doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

React works a little bit different than a pure HTML form element, in which you POST the selected value to a server, in react the selection of something is handled by the virtual DOM, so you will get the selected value in your component state, when you submit the form, the `handleSubmit` method triggers and in there you can use the state value to do something, like an API call to submit your data.

Since you're using `event.preventDefault()` the submission won't work the way it should, because you stopped the event and in turn, you tell react, let me handle this my own way.

```
handleSubmit (event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const flavor = this.state.value;

  // validate the flavor here
  if (!flavor) return;

  // make a call to an API to do something with the data
  axios.post('/save', { data: flavor }).then({
    // do something else if the call succeeds
    // example: clear the state or show something in the UI like a success notice
  }).catch(e => {
    // or handle the error
    return e
  })
}
```

Comment: Sorry, that code is from the React docs to show that their example does not work (you have to do inspect to see this though).  I've added my code above that is doing the submit;  you can see that even though it calls event.preventDefault(), it subsequently calls event.currentTarget.submit() to complete the submit.  So I only stopped the default if validation fails; if validation succeeds then the submit will happen.  This issue is that there is no option element with a selected value in the real dom when the submit happens, so the encoded form values do not reflect the state.